# How to set up a 404 page to retain the original URL?

Tags: wordpress, apache, http-status-code-404

I've found hundreds of blogs and articles telling me "NOT to use my '/404-page/' as the URL slug but retain the original one," and not one describing how I can actually do that.

Right now I have my website on Wordpress and I created a custom 404 page which I load in 404.php.
What am I supposed to do to retain the originally 'mistyped' URL and keep the 404 response? I need this for analytics because right now I can see if a user lands on the 404 page, but I have no clue what he was looking for originally.

I'm guessing this is something in the htaccess?

I'm using an Apache server.

Answer (score -1):

I found a good Wordpress plugin that would do the work for you...

https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/all-404-redirect-to-homepage/

Comment: That is the last thing I want to do. The 404 page has it's own purpose and I have no intention of forwarding it to my front page. At least that was the only thing I could understand since everything else about this un-updated and unverified plugin is in German.

Comment: There are of course other plugins that you can use. This should only be an example.